# QR-code in beamer footline

Tags: beamer, qrcode

For some reason, using a `qrcode` package in `beamer` footline produces an invalid QR-code.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{qrcode}
\newcommand{\insertqrcode}{%
  \qrcode{http://www.ctan.org}
}

% Add qrcode to footline
\setbeamertemplate{footline}{\insertqrcode}

% Same result
%\defbeamertemplate*{footline}{qrcode}{\insertqrcode}
%\setbeamertemplate{footline}[qrcode]

\begin{document}
  \begin{frame}
    \qrcode{http://www.ctan.org}
    \insertqrcode
  \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

As you can see the height is stretched, which generates the invalid QR-code.

[image: resulting pdf]

```
*File List*
  beamer.cls    2017/01/23 v3.41 A class for typesetting presentations
etoolbox.sty    2017/01/02 v2.4 e-TeX tools for LaTeX (JAW)
beamerbasemodes.sty    
beamerbasedecode.sty    
   ifpdf.sty    2017/03/15 v3.2 Provides the ifpdf switch
beamerbaseoptions.sty    
  keyval.sty    2014/10/28 v1.15 key=value parser (DPC)
geometry.sty    2010/09/12 v5.6 Page Geometry
  ifvtex.sty    2016/05/16 v1.6 Detect VTeX and its facilities (HO)
 ifxetex.sty    2010/09/12 v0.6 Provides ifxetex conditional
  size11.clo    2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
 pgfcore.sty    2010/04/11 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.7)
graphicx.sty    2014/10/28 v1.0g Enhanced LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
graphics.sty    2016/10/09 v1.0u Standard LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
    trig.sty    2016/01/03 v1.10 sin cos tan (DPC)
graphics.cfg    2016/06/04 v1.11 sample graphics configuration
  pdftex.def    2017/01/12 v0.06k Graphics/color for pdfTeX
infwarerr.sty    2016/05/16 v1.4 Providing info/warning/error messages (HO)
 ltxcmds.sty    2016/05/16 v1.23 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO)
  pgfsys.sty    2014/07/09 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.48)
  pgfrcs.sty    2015/08/07 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.31)
everyshi.sty    2001/05/15 v3.00 EveryShipout Package (MS)
  pgfrcs.code.tex
  pgfsys.code.tex
pgfsyssoftpath.code.tex    2013/09/09  (rcs-revision 1.9)
pgfsysprotocol.code.tex    2006/10/16  (rcs-revision 1.4)
  xcolor.sty    2016/05/11 v2.12 LaTeX color extensions (UK)
   color.cfg    2016/01/02 v1.6 sample color configuration
 pgfcore.code.tex
 xxcolor.sty    2003/10/24 ver 0.1
atbegshi.sty    2016/06/09 v1.18 At begin shipout hook (HO)
hyperref.sty    2017/03/14 v6.85a Hypertext links for LaTeX
hobsub-hyperref.sty    2016/05/16 v1.14 Bundle oberdiek, subset hyperref (HO)
hobsub-generic.sty    2016/05/16 v1.14 Bundle oberdiek, subset generic (HO)
  hobsub.sty    2016/05/16 v1.14 Construct package bundles (HO)
ifluatex.sty    2016/05/16 v1.4 Provides the ifluatex switch (HO)
 intcalc.sty    2016/05/16 v1.2 Expandable calculations with integers (HO)
etexcmds.sty    2016/05/16 v1.6 Avoid name clashes with e-TeX commands (HO)
kvsetkeys.sty    2016/05/16 v1.17 Key value parser (HO)
kvdefinekeys.sty    2016/05/16 v1.4 Define keys (HO)
pdftexcmds.sty    2017/03/19 v0.25 Utility functions of pdfTeX for LuaTeX (HO)
pdfescape.sty    2016/05/16 v1.14 Implements pdfTeX's escape features (HO)
bigintcalc.sty    2016/05/16 v1.4 Expandable calculations on big integers (HO)
  bitset.sty    2016/05/16 v1.2 Handle bit-vector datatype (HO)
uniquecounter.sty    2016/05/16 v1.3 Provide unlimited unique counter (HO)
letltxmacro.sty    2016/05/16 v1.5 Let assignment for LaTeX macros (HO)
 hopatch.sty    2016/05/16 v1.3 Wrapper for package hooks (HO)
xcolor-patch.sty    2016/05/16 xcolor patch
atveryend.sty    2016/05/16 v1.9 Hooks at the very end of document (HO)
refcount.sty    2016/05/16 v3.5 Data extraction from label references (HO)
 hycolor.sty    2016/05/16 v1.8 Color options for hyperref/bookmark (HO)
 auxhook.sty    2016/05/16 v1.4 Hooks for auxiliary files (HO)
kvoptions.sty    2016/05/16 v3.12 Key value format for package options (HO)
  pd1enc.def    2017/03/14 v6.85a Hyperref: PDFDocEncoding definition (HO)
hyperref.cfg    2002/06/06 v1.2 hyperref configuration of TeXLive
     url.sty    2013/09/16  ver 3.4  Verb mode for urls, etc.
 hpdftex.def    2017/03/14 v6.85a Hyperref driver for pdfTeX
rerunfilecheck.sty    2016/05/16 v1.8 Rerun checks for auxiliary files (HO)
beamerbaserequires.sty    
beamerbasecompatibility.sty    
beamerbasefont.sty    
 amssymb.sty    2013/01/14 v3.01 AMS font symbols
amsfonts.sty    2013/01/14 v3.01 Basic AMSFonts support
sansmathaccent.sty    2013/03/28
filehook.sty    2011/10/12 v0.5d Hooks for input files
beamerbasetranslator.sty    
translator.sty    2010/06/12 ver 1.10
translator-language-mappings.tex
beamerbasemisc.sty    
beamerbasetwoscreens.sty    
beamerbaseoverlay.sty    
beamerbasetitle.sty    
beamerbasesection.sty    
beamerbaseframe.sty    
beamerbaseverbatim.sty    
beamerbaseframesize.sty    
beamerbaseframecomponents.sty    
beamerbasecolor.sty    
beamerbasenotes.sty    
beamerbasetoc.sty    
beamerbasetemplates.sty    
beamerbaseauxtemplates.sty    
beamerbaseboxes.sty    
beamerbaselocalstructure.sty    
enumerate.sty    2015/07/23 v3.00 enumerate extensions (DPC)
beamerbasenavigation.sty    
beamerbasetheorems.sty    
 amsmath.sty    2016/11/05 v2.16a AMS math features
 amstext.sty    2000/06/29 v2.01 AMS text
  amsgen.sty    1999/11/30 v2.0 generic functions
  amsbsy.sty    1999/11/29 v1.2d Bold Symbols
  amsopn.sty    2016/03/08 v2.02 operator names
  amsthm.sty    2015/03/04 v2.20.2
beamerbasethemes.sty    
beamerthemedefault.sty    
beamerfontthemedefault.sty    
beamercolorthemedefault.sty    
beamerinnerthemedefault.sty    
beamerouterthemedefault.sty    
  qrcode.sty    2015/01/08 v1.51 QR code generation
 xkeyval.sty    2014/12/03 v2.7a package option processing (HA)
 xkeyval.tex    2014/12/03 v2.7a key=value parser (HA)
supp-pdf.mkii
epstopdf-base.sty    2016/05/15 v2.6 Base part for package epstopdf
  grfext.sty    2016/05/16 v1.2 Manage graphics extensions (HO)
epstopdf-sys.cfg    2010/07/13 v1.3 Configuration of (r)epstopdf for TeX Live
 nameref.sty    2016/05/21 v2.44 Cross-referencing by name of section
gettitlestring.sty    2016/05/16 v1.5 Cleanup title references (HO)
     aaa.out
     aaa.out
translator-basic-dictionary-English.dict    
translator-bibliography-dictionary-English.dict    
translator-environment-dictionary-English.dict    
translator-months-dictionary-English.dict    
translator-numbers-dictionary-English.dict    
translator-theorem-dictionary-English.dict    
    umsa.fd    2013/01/14 v3.01 AMS symbols A
    umsb.fd    2013/01/14 v3.01 AMS symbols B
ot1mathkerncmss.fd    2013/03/27 Fontinst v1.933 font definitions for OT1/mathk
erncmss.
***********
```

Comment: Could you please add why you do not use a `frame` environment? In any case, you could use a `\savebox`.

Comment: @mamot I didn't add the `frame` environment in my MWE because I forgot it. Nevertheless, it makes no difference. I will see with the `\savebox`.

Answer (score 3):

Well, after compiling your code with my current MiKTeX 2.9 I can see no error messages and no error in the resulting pdf. I added `\listfiles` as first command to get the list of used packages and version numbers in the log file:

```
 *File List*
  beamer.cls    2018/12/02 v3.55 A class for typesetting presentations
beamerbasemodes.sty    
etoolbox.sty    2018/08/19 v2.5f e-TeX tools for LaTeX (JAW)
beamerbasedecode.sty    
   ifpdf.sty    2018/09/07 v3.3 Provides the ifpdf switch
beamerbaseoptions.sty    
  keyval.sty    2014/10/28 v1.15 key=value parser (DPC)
geometry.sty    2018/04/16 v5.8 Page Geometry
  ifvtex.sty    2016/05/16 v1.6 Detect VTeX and its facilities (HO)
 ifxetex.sty    2010/09/12 v0.6 Provides ifxetex conditional
geometry.cfg
  size11.clo    2018/09/03 v1.4i Standard LaTeX file (size option)
 pgfcore.sty    2019/04/04 v3.1.2 (3.1.2)
graphicx.sty    2017/06/01 v1.1a Enhanced LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
graphics.sty    2017/06/25 v1.2c Standard LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
    trig.sty    2016/01/03 v1.10 sin cos tan (DPC)
graphics.cfg    2016/06/04 v1.11 sample graphics configuration
  pdftex.def    2018/01/08 v1.0l Graphics/color driver for pdftex
  pgfsys.sty    2019/04/04 v3.1.2 (3.1.2)
  pgfrcs.sty    2019/04/04 v3.1.2 (3.1.2)
everyshi.sty    2001/05/15 v3.00 EveryShipout Package (MS)
  pgfrcs.code.tex
  pgfsys.code.tex
pgfsyssoftpath.code.tex    2019/04/04 v3.1.2 (3.1.2)
pgfsysprotocol.code.tex    2019/04/04 v3.1.2 (3.1.2)
  xcolor.sty    2016/05/11 v2.12 LaTeX color extensions (UK)
   color.cfg    2016/01/02 v1.6 sample color configuration
 pgfcore.code.tex
 xxcolor.sty    2003/10/24 ver 0.1
atbegshi.sty    2016/06/09 v1.18 At begin shipout hook (HO)
infwarerr.sty    2016/05/16 v1.4 Providing info/warning/error messages (HO)
 ltxcmds.sty    2016/05/16 v1.23 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO)
hyperref.sty    2018/11/30 v6.88e Hypertext links for LaTeX
hobsub-hyperref.sty    2016/05/16 v1.14 Bundle oberdiek, subset hyperref (HO)
hobsub-generic.sty    2016/05/16 v1.14 Bundle oberdiek, subset generic (HO)
  hobsub.sty    2016/05/16 v1.14 Construct package bundles (HO)
ifluatex.sty    2016/05/16 v1.4 Provides the ifluatex switch (HO)
 intcalc.sty    2016/05/16 v1.2 Expandable calculations with integers (HO)
etexcmds.sty    2016/05/16 v1.6 Avoid name clashes with e-TeX commands (HO)
kvsetkeys.sty    2016/05/16 v1.17 Key value parser (HO)
kvdefinekeys.sty    2016/05/16 v1.4 Define keys (HO)
pdftexcmds.sty    2018/09/10 v0.29 Utility functions of pdfTeX for LuaTeX (HO)
pdfescape.sty    2016/05/16 v1.14 Implements pdfTeX's escape features (HO)
bigintcalc.sty    2016/05/16 v1.4 Expandable calculations on big integers (HO)
  bitset.sty    2016/05/16 v1.2 Handle bit-vector datatype (HO)
uniquecounter.sty    2016/05/16 v1.3 Provide unlimited unique counter (HO)
letltxmacro.sty    2016/05/16 v1.5 Let assignment for LaTeX macros (HO)
 hopatch.sty    2016/05/16 v1.3 Wrapper for package hooks (HO)
xcolor-patch.sty    2016/05/16 xcolor patch
atveryend.sty    2016/05/16 v1.9 Hooks at the very end of document (HO)
refcount.sty    2016/05/16 v3.5 Data extraction from label references (HO)
 hycolor.sty    2016/05/16 v1.8 Color options for hyperref/bookmark (HO)
 auxhook.sty    2016/05/16 v1.4 Hooks for auxiliary files (HO)
kvoptions.sty    2016/05/16 v3.12 Key value format for package options (HO)
  pd1enc.def    2018/11/30 v6.88e Hyperref: PDFDocEncoding definition (HO)
hyperref.cfg    2002/06/06 v1.2 hyperref configuration of TeXLive
     url.sty    2013/09/16  ver 3.4  Verb mode for urls, etc.
 hpdftex.def    2018/11/30 v6.88e Hyperref driver for pdfTeX
rerunfilecheck.sty    2016/05/16 v1.8 Rerun checks for auxiliary files (HO)
beamerbaserequires.sty    
beamerbasecompatibility.sty    
beamerbasefont.sty    
 amssymb.sty    2013/01/14 v3.01 AMS font symbols
amsfonts.sty    2013/01/14 v3.01 Basic AMSFonts support
sansmathaccent.sty    2013/03/28
filehook.sty    2011/10/12 v0.5d Hooks for input files
beamerbasetranslator.sty    
translator.sty    2018/01/04 v1.12 Easy translation of strings in LaTeX
beamerbasemisc.sty    
beamerbasetwoscreens.sty    
beamerbaseoverlay.sty    
beamerbasetitle.sty    
beamerbasesection.sty    
beamerbaseframe.sty    
beamerbaseverbatim.sty    
beamerbaseframesize.sty    
beamerbaseframecomponents.sty    
beamerbasecolor.sty    
beamerbasenotes.sty    
beamerbasetoc.sty    
beamerbasetemplates.sty    
beamerbaseauxtemplates.sty    
beamerbaseboxes.sty    
beamerbaselocalstructure.sty    
enumerate.sty    2015/07/23 v3.00 enumerate extensions (DPC)
beamerbasenavigation.sty    
beamerbasetheorems.sty    
 amsmath.sty    2018/12/01 v2.17b AMS math features
 amstext.sty    2000/06/29 v2.01 AMS text
  amsgen.sty    1999/11/30 v2.0 generic functions
  amsbsy.sty    1999/11/29 v1.2d Bold Symbols
  amsopn.sty    2016/03/08 v2.02 operator names
  amsthm.sty    2017/10/31 v2.20.4
beamerbasethemes.sty    
beamerthemedefault.sty    
beamerfontthemedefault.sty    
beamercolorthemedefault.sty    
beamerinnerthemedefault.sty    
beamerouterthemedefault.sty    
  qrcode.sty    2015/01/08 v1.51 QR code generation
 xkeyval.sty    2014/12/03 v2.7a package option processing (HA)
 xkeyval.tex    2014/12/03 v2.7a key=value parser (HA)
supp-pdf.mkii
epstopdf-base.sty    2016/05/15 v2.6 Base part for package epstopdf
  grfext.sty    2016/05/16 v1.2 Manage graphics extensions (HO)
 nameref.sty    2016/05/21 v2.44 Cross-referencing by name of section
gettitlestring.sty    2016/05/16 v1.5 Cleanup title references (HO)
  487409.out
  487409.out
translator-basic-dictionary-English.dict    
translator-bibliography-dictionary-English.dict    
translator-environment-dictionary-English.dict    
translator-months-dictionary-English.dict    
translator-numbers-dictionary-English.dict    
translator-theorem-dictionary-English.dict    
    umsa.fd    2013/01/14 v3.01 AMS symbols A
    umsb.fd    2013/01/14 v3.01 AMS symbols B
ot1mathkerncmss.fd    2013/03/27 Fontinst v1.933 font definitions for OT1/mathkerncmss.
 ***********
```

The resulting pdf is:

[image: resulting pdf]

Please add `\listfiles` to your `mwe.tex` and compile (please use the given mwe in your question to get a result you can compare with mine!).  Then compare the resulting list of used packages and version numbers with mine. I guess you have some older ones ... Have you considered to update your system (do not do it if you a short of a deadline!)?

Comment: I believe you are right that I have some package outdated. But as, you said, close to a deadline, so no update... Unless it is a particular package.